# Nextjs active navigation bar with styled-components

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I just started learning about Nextjs and I have this navigation bar made with `styled-components`. But the problem is I am trying to highlight the current page on the navigation bar and could not figure it out.

`.js file`

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

...

const Header = () => {
  const [toggle, toggleNav] = useState(false)
  const router = useRouter();
    
  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        <li className={router.pathname == "/home" ? "active" : ""}>
          <Link href="/home">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li className={router.pathname == "/about_us" ? "active" : ""}>
          <Link href="/about_us">About Us</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </>
  )
}
```

`globals.css`

```css
li.active {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66061638/how-to-style-link-component-when-on-active-page-on-next-js

Answer (score 2):

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
const ListItem = ({ className, children, isActive }) => (
  isActive ? <NormalListItem className={className}>
    {children}
  </NormalListItem> : <ActiveListItem className={className}>
    {children}
  </ActiveListItem>
);
const NormalListItem = ({ className, children }) => (
  <li className={className}>
    {children}
  </li>
);

const ActiveListItem = styled(NormalListItem)`
  color: red;
`;
```

In the component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

...

const Header = () => {
  const [toggle, toggleNav] = useState(false)
  const router = useRouter();
    
  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        <ListItem className="list-class" isActive={router.pathname == "/home"}>
          <Link href="/home">Home</Link>
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem className="list-class" isActive={router.pathname == "/about_us"}>
          <Link href="/about_us">About Us</Link>
        </ListItem>
      </ul>
    </>
  )
}
```

You can try this sort of solution for your component.

Comment: This one works but it just doesn't change the Link color. Guess I need to figure out how to change this next/link element. Thank you by the way!